# Python datetime object not displaying the correct date

Tags: python, date, datetime

I'm trying to convert an `UTC` string to a python `datetime` object.

The string I want to convert is: `2016-12-16T23:00:00.000Z` and it is in `UTC` format. When I convert code to a different timezone I get `2016-12-16 23:00:00+01:00` which is a correct behaviour.

My question is, why when I access the `datetime` object, the day is still `16` and not `17`, as I would expect to happen when `1 hour` is added to `23:00`.

What am I missing?

> My code

```
tz = pytz.timezone("Europe/Ljubljana")
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z")
date = tz.localize(dt)

print 'Date: ', date.strftime('%d')
print 'Date: ', date
```

> Result

```
Date:  16
Date:  2016-12-16 23:00:00+01:00
```

Comment: try using date = pytz.utc.normalize(tz.localize(dt)) or you need to put some offset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. `dt` has no time zone set. When you call `tz.localize(dt)`, you simply assign the timezone.

Here's what you want to do:

```
tz = pytz.timezone("Europe/Ljubljana")
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z")
dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc) # you specify the time is UTC
print dt.astimezone(tz) # and now you convert dt to your preferred timezone
```

You obtain:

```
datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 17, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Ljubljana' CET+1:00:00 STD>)
```